# String slicing in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to slice the last four characters off a character array, and I tried the method that Python uses without success;

```
char *charone = (char*)("I need the last four")
char *chartwo = charone[-4:]

cout << chartwo << endl;
```

I would want this code to return:

```
four
```

But C/C++ doesn't seem to be that easy...

Where could I find a simple alternative that will return the last four characters of one character array into another character array?

Comment: Why do you cast? Is it because you are using gcc and it gives a warning?

Comment: Yeah XP, and when I don't I get a Segmentation Fault usually.

Comment: Right, in C++ string literals are const char, so you should use a const char* to point at it. That is probably what the compiler tells you too.

Comment: What does `[-4:]` mean, what language is it?

Comment: @icepack it's Python slicing, I believe. It means go four characters backwards in the array and slice to the end.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
int len = strlen(charone);
char *chartwo = charone + (len < 4 ? 0 : len - 4);
```

In C++, you can replace that with:

```
char* chartwo = charone + (std::max)(strlen(charone), 4) - 4;
```

The code uses a special property of C strings that only works for chopping off the beginning of a string.

Comment: Your method is more robust, but mine is a compile-time constant. ;-) So, pros and cons of each, I guess. :-)

Comment: @Chris compiler optimization should make them the same.

Comment: @mathepic: The version he is talking about is probably the one that used 16 as the offset (assuming the string length was 20) and didn't compute the length of the string at all; the compiler might be able to evaluate `strlen` on a constant string, but I don't know if any do.

Comment: @Jeremiah gcc does, I just ran a test. Both versions generate the same assembly code under -O2.

Comment: Hmmmm, I think not. In python, after the slice, you would expect charone and chartwo to be two different strings. If you later change charone to "I need the last four digits", should chartwo be "four" or "gits"? In python, it would still be "four" but in this answer and any answer without an explicit copy, chartwo will be "gits"... is this the behavior you want?

Comment: oops bad example. say you later change charone to "I need the last 4444" -- then chartwo will be "4444" and no longer "four"

Comment: @jmilloy: Since these are pointers to a string literal, modifying it is already undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jeremiah gcc evaluates strlen(constantstring) at compile-time. Others _should_, but don't.

Comment: @Fred As is common, this is just an example. The OP has stated that the real code works with dynamic strings, in which case jmilloy's point is valid. It's generally a good idea to think about the general case and not get too language-lawyerly about undefined behavior in specific cases.

Comment: @JimBalter: Better yet: make the example case match the actual case.  The OP doesn't even make it clear it didn't match in this aspect except on the (current) lowest-voted answer.

Comment: @It's not my example, and I wasn't responding to the OP, I was responding to you.

Comment: @Fred: yes, but i suspect that the example is a simplified one. The question may not be looking for a solution to string literals, but to character arrays in general. (@Jim, thanks and sorry to repeat)

Comment: @Fred: If we're going to be pedantic, he's looking for a solution that will "return the last four characters", which then must be a function that allocates memory, makes the copy, and returns a pointer to the new memory.

Comment: @JimBalter: You were responding to me and I was responding to you, and...?  I don't see what you're pointing out.  I'm sorry I missed the vital comment buried on that other answer.

Comment: @Fred The point is that you're giving _me_ advice directed to the _OP_. Your "Better yet" is simply a non sequitur to my comment. The reality is that questions posted here are generally not going to fit such guidelines but that's no reason to wave away a good and valid point -- like the one jmilloy made.

Answer (score 7):

First, let's remove the deprecated conversion:

```
char const *charone = "I need the last four";
```

Arrays are not first-class values in C++, and they don't support slicing.  However, just as the above charone points to the first item in the array, you can point to any other item.  Pointers are used with chars to make C-style strings: the pointed-to char up until a null char is the contents of the string.  Because the characters you want are at the end of the current (charone) string, you can point at the "f":

```
char const *chartwo = charone + 16;
```

Or, to handle arbitrary string values:

```
char const *charone = "from this arbitrary string value, I need the last four";
int charone_len = strlen(charone);
assert(charone_len >= 4);  // Or other error-checking.
char const *chartwo = charone + charone_len - 4;
```

Or, because you're using C++:

```
std::string one = "from this arbitrary string value, I need the last four";
assert(one.size() >= 4);  // Or other error-checking, since one.size() - 4
// might underflow (size_type is unsigned).
std::string two = one.substr(one.size() - 4);

// To mimic Python's [-4:] meaning "up to the last four":
std::string three = one.substr(one.size() < 4 ? 0 : one.size() - 4);
// E.g. if one == "ab", then three == "ab".
```

In particular, note that std::string gives you *distinct* values, so modifying either string doesn't modify the other as happens with pointers.

Answer (score 6):

C++ and Python are very different. C++ does not have built-in Python-like string facilities, but its [Standard Template Library](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/) has a handy [`std::string`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html) type, which you should look into.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to just briefly access the last four characters, then something like

```
char* chartwo = charone + (strlen(charone) - 4);
```

will be fine (plus some error checking).

**But if you want to replicate the python functionality**, you will need to **copy** the last four characters. Again, use strlen to get the length (or store it somewhere beforehand), and then use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) (or probably a better stl function that has the same function). something like...

```
char chartwo[5];
strcpy(chartwo, charone + strlen(charone) - 4);
```

(Note: If you don't copy, then you can't free charone until you are finished using chartwo. Also, If you don't copy, then if you change charone later, chartwo will  change as well. If that's okay, then sure, just point to the offset.)

Comment: Good point about copying, however don't forget to allocate space for chartwo to point to.  Leave off the ", 4" (which is an error for strcpy) as we know we're copying the terminating null (and be careful to correctly null-terminate with strncpy if you need to copy from the middle).

Comment: Better, but chartwo needs a length of 5. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
char* chartwo = charone + 16;
```

Comment: My char arrays are going to be dynamic so this probably won't work

Answer (score 1):

array slicing in c++:

```
array<char, 13> msg  = {"Hello world!"};
array<char, 6>  part = {"world"};

// this line generates no instructions and does not copy data
// It just tells the compiler how to interpret the bits
array<char, 5>& myslice = *reinterpret_cast<array<char,5>*>(&msg[6]); 

// now they are the same length and we can compare them
if( myslice == part )
   cout<< "huzzah";
```

This is just one of the emamples where slicing is usefull

I have made a small library which does this with compile-time bounds checks at https://github.com/Erikvv/array-slicing-cpp

Comment: Interesting approach for actual arrays. However, it requires more code to make it work for strings as myslice is not zero terminated. Additionally, that comparison won't work as the arrays sizes are different. Hence I'm downvoting as this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Doesn't this violate strict aliasing?

Comment: @im_infamous Yeah sure I don't recommend you do this now that we have std::string_view